# How do I write frontend "ajax"

Tags: ajax

I am working on a project on a marriage website. On that page I have created a new section for `recently added profile`. I have written the code in the backend but in the frontend what should I write to call the backend code?

I have used technique but it's not working.

Here is the code that I have written in the Controller:

```
module.exports.recent = function(req, res) {
    User.find({}).sort('-created').limit(5).exec(function(err, data){
      if (err) 
      {
        return res.status(400).json({
           message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
         })
      }
      res.json(req.profile,{
        user: req.user || null,
        request: req,
        users: data
      });

    });
};
```

The code that I have written in the route

```
app.route('/recent').get(users.recent);
```

Answer (score 0):

To broadly answer your question of 'how do I call the backend code from the frontend?' - you don't. You make a request to the route that runs your code, and then send back (likely with `res.json`) a response. There is no way to directly call the code, so you'll need to make an AJAX request (as you've identified).

You can use a couple of things. The easiest, if you're on a modern browser, is a function `fetch`. `fetch` is a low-level API for doing AJAX calls from the browser, and comes built-in to most modern browsers.

```
fetch('/recent')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(myResult => { /* do what you want with the result here */ })
```

You can learn more about `fetch` from MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Because `fetch` is quite low-level, there are various wrappers written over it to make life easier. My preference is `axios`, which you can read more about at https://github.com/axios/axios.  The following code is the equivalent with `axios`:

```
axios.get('/recent')
  .then(res => res.data)
  .then(myResult => { /* do what you want with the result here */ })
```

`axios` really comes into its own when you're performing more complex queries. It supports a UMD bundle via `unpkg` - just drop `<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>` onto your HTML page, and you'll have access to `axios` globally on the window object.

Comment: So if i put  fetch('/recent')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(myResult => { /* do what you want with the result here */ }) in the user view which is a home.ejs this should fetch the data?